# Access Mapping node with python

Tags: python, node-editor

Have problem similar to this but that workaround does not work for me.
[Empty bpy.data.node_groups](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39591/empty-bpy-data-node-groups)

I need to access mapping node with Python so I can change values. This code worked for several times I used script but suddenly it does not work anymore.

```
bpy.data.node_groups["NodeGroup"].nodes["Mapping"].rotation[2] = math.radians(180)
```

Also looking at python output when changing values manually and looking at tooltip path output I should use something like this.

```
bpy.data.node_groups["Shader NodeTree"].nodes["Mapping"].rotation[2] = math.radians(180)
```

But I get error that Shader Nodetree does not exist.

Can anyone explain what is going on here, am I missing something here?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31390/cycles-material-what-is-the-syntax-to-access-texture-mapping-location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since *Mapping* is a shader tree node, a 'material reference' is required:

```
import bpy
import math

# get the material
mat = bpy.data.materials['Material']

# get all material nodes
nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes

# get the mapping node
map_node = nodes.get("Mapping")

# set the rotation z component
map_node.rotation[2] = math.radians(180)
```

Direct access:

```
rot_z = math.radians(180)
bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes['Mapping'].rotation[2] = rot_z
```

**Result:**

[image]

#### Other properties

```
# set the vector type to 'TEXTURE'`, 'POINT', 'VECTOR' or 'NORMAL'
map_node.vector_type = "NORMAL"

# set the location components
map_node.translation = (0, 1, 3)

# set scale values
map_node.scale = (1, 0.5, 1)

# use minimum clipping value
map_node.use_min = True
map_node.min = (1,1,1)

# use max clipping value
map_node.use_max = True
map_node.max = (0,0,1)
```

**Result:**

[image]

---

For the [**world environment**](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/world.html?highlight=world) it's basically the same:

```
# get the world
world = bpy.data.worlds['World']

# get all material nodes
nodes = world.node_tree.nodes

# get the mapping node
map_node = nodes.get("Mapping")

# set the rotation z component
map_node.rotation[2] = math.radians(180)
```

Direct access:

```
rot_z = math.radians(180)
bpy.data.worlds['World'].node_tree.nodes["Mapping"].rotation[2] = rot_z
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks this was helpful, I have Mapping node in environmet, I manage to figure out how to access it.

Comment: @SreckoMicic You are welcome :) I've updated the answer.

Comment: @poor Is there some way to do this in the game engine?

Comment: @christai Unfortunately I have no experience with *Game Engine*. Not sure whether there is a way using nodes for the world background in GE at all, but if this works it's the same process. Otherwise better ask a new question with game engine tag. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @poor Okay, thanks anyway. This topic of accessing material nodes in the Game Engine has been bugging me crazy, so thanks anyway for your input :)